# Handling invalid image source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a view that is binded to a string resouce in viewmodel, and it works just fine with links to images on the web or harddrive image files. However in case a bad image source is selected, the image does not show for obvious reasons. Is there a binding i could do to see if image had a valid source or is there a way to put a default image, if source is bad.

Property in ViewModel:

```
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set
        {
            imageSource = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("ImageSource");
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Name="picture" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="auto" Width="auto" MaxWidth="750" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

binding works fine.

Comment: Make a converter which checks the image source for validity, and returns the default value if not valid?

Comment: or just validate at setter or getter of public property.

Comment: Either a custom converter or a simple addition to your getter: `get { if(!File.Exists(imageSource)) { return "default message"; } else { return imageSource; } }` (just some quick pseudo code, you would have to provide alternate logic for web images and so on)

Comment: alright, image source used tho can both be online or offline as it is now, guess i just have to check if its a correct Uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ImageSource is guaranteed to be null for a bad image then you can use a data trigger:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Name="picture" Height="auto" Width="auto" MaxWidth="750" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ImageSource}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ImageSource}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="default_image.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Lets say i would prefer an empty string, would i be able to do value=""

Comment: Awesome, well this its just do this combined with a validator, and this is the answer i needed thank you

Comment: Just to mention, this has one small side effect: **It overwrites the implicit style.** Well, you probably don't have implicit styles for images, but for other elements it is quite common. You should then the set BasedOn property of the explicit style: `<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Image}}">`

Answer (score 3):

Binding has `TargetNullValue` property that targets exactly your scenario:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, 
                        TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultImage}}" />
```

of course, the resource has to be defined somewhere: `<BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultImage" UriSource="default_image" />`

Comment: Nice, i guess, with this property its basically like doing the data trigger like in Mark's answer. Still nice to know that bindings has that property, this i bet i could use in multiple scenarios.

Comment: you could also use Converter to to the same. XAML is also code and you should keep it simple, readable and maintanable. If you can replace 10 lines of xaml code with one, go for it

Comment: I Agree currently with the image, its just this place, but if something come up in the project where its repeatable i will definitly use this method